# Python reading from csv into dictionary and adding numeric values to dictionary

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I am having some trouble working out some code for two parts of a program I am writing. Basically, I have a csv file that contains player names for a game and each name is in a different row in the first column of the file. I am wanting to read these player names into a global dictionary in Python so that the dictionary looks like:

```
playerDict = {P1:0, P2:0, P3:0, P4:0, P5:0, P6:0}
```

Secondly, my program through other code puts players into a list in order of their placement in a game that looks like:

```
playerPlacements = [P2, P3, P1]
```

Basically what I am wanting to do is add a value of 5 to each player in the dictionary that is found in the 'playerPlacements' list so that the dictionary will look like:

```
playerDict = {P1:5, P2:5, P3:5, P4:0, P5:0, P6:0}
```

I have already searched around to try and figure out how to do this and I have still been unable to work it out so any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

**Setup**

```
playerDict = {'P1' : 0,  'P2' : 0, 'P3' : 0, 'P4' : 0, 'P5' : 0, 'P6' : 0}
playerPlacements = ['P2', 'P3', 'P1']
```

Use the `collections.Counter` data structure to do this quite painlessly:

```
from collections import Counter

c = Counter(playerDict)
c.update(Counter(playerPlacements * 5))

print(c)
Counter({'P1': 5, 'P2': 5, 'P3': 5, 'P4': 0, 'P5': 0, 'P6': 0})
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the feedback, I have tried this but I am getting a Traceback error that says: Traceback (most recent call last):
    c = Counter(playerDict)
NameError: name 'Counter' is not defined

Comment: @Sean When someone suggests something like `collections.Counter`, that means `Counter` isn't a builtin, it's in a module called `collections`. Read the tutorial on imports, but the quick answer here is `from collections import Counter`.

Comment: @Sean If your question was answered, please vote on, and accept it, thanks.